# Why does this code not work in Microsoft Ria?

Tags: c#, ado.net-entity-data-model

### link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee796239%28v=vs.91%29.aspx#Y3078

### the code

```
return this.ObjectContext.SalesOrderHeaders.OrderBy(e=>e.SalesOrderID);
```

### note

- have done and checked everything done till now is according to the tutorial
- my table is named SERVER,

so something like, the following should work,

```
return this.ObjectContext.SERVERs.OrderBy(e=>e.username);
```

### prob

Visual Studio 2010 says that there is no "e".

### EDIT THE ERRORS-

```
Error   13  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type D:\DOCUMENTSS\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ExampleBusinessApplication\ExampleBusinessApplication.Web\DomainService1.cs   35  55  ExampleBusinessApplication.Web


Error   14  A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else D:\DOCUMENTSS\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ExampleBusinessApplication\ExampleBusinessApplication.Web\DomainService1.cs   35  55  ExampleBusinessApplication.Web
```

Comment: More information needed.You cannot use e in lambda, as an error message you posted already mentioned that.  Need more information to identify exact lambda expression error.

Comment: know the error, how to solve it? this e thing is not there, how to declare it, or what to do?, what information do you need>, i guess this is a stupid question :-) i donot know the meaning of the syntax => but on changing the e to d it works :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message *appears to be* telling you that `e` is already defined as something (presumably a string) elsewhere in the scope that contains your `return` statement. Without seeing your code, I can only conjecture that you have something like this:

```
method()
{
  string e = "abcd";

  return this.ObjectContext.SERVERs.OrderBy(e=>e.username);
}
```

That isn't going to work, because the symbol you're trying to use as an argument to a lambda expression *is already declared*.

If you don't understand the use of `=>` syntax for declaring delegates, you owe it to yourself to figure that out. :) [Here's a tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/03/lambda-expressions.aspx), for example.